# How to print a bigint in F#?

Tags: f#, string-formatting, biginteger

I am trying to find out how to print out the value of a `bigint` or `System.Numerics.BigInteger` in F#. I have found a site [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/) that attempts to explain how to do this, but in the Visual Studio editor, it is flagged as an error. So far, I am just trying something simple like:

```
printfn "bigInt: %A " 123456789I
```

But that gets flagged as:

[image: Error]

Why does this not work? How can I print out a `bigint`?

Code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main = 
   printfn "bigInt: %A " 123456789I
```

Comment: `printfn "bigInt: %A " 123456789I` - works for me both in VS2013 and 2015

Comment: I am guessing that this is surronded by an `if` and you don't have the same return types on both sides

Comment: Actually, it is in the main function. Sorry, I'll post my code.

Comment: Main needs to return an int and take arguments - something like `let main argv = printf ... \n 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using an explicit entry point, `main` needs to accept a single `string[]` argument and return `int`. Your sample code is missing both of those requirements. Your `printfn` line is fine.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (argv : string[]) =
    printfn "bigint %A" 12345I
    0
```